# jQuery - Cloning once elements with same class (can't figure it out)

Tags: jquery, html

I have some items that I want to clone. The items are nested into a three-level collapsable structure (made with Bootstrap). Each item has a unique id for other purposes.

Anyway, here's my issue:

I want to write a code which can let me clone elements on click and I want to write it once and for all (I could write a code for each element but I'd need around 150 pieces of code).

All elements I'm trying to clone have the same class (.h5 for titles and .soft for descriptions) and that's the thing I want to target in the jQuery, but any time I click on the element, it clones all the elements with the targeted class that it can find on the page.

I want my code to clone the content of .h5 (and .soft) of the specific  on which the user clicks. Right now, when users click on an , it clones all .h5 contents, not just the ones in that particular .

I'm not sure if you can understand what I mean. Here's my code as a reference:

**HTML (Portion)**

```
    <ul id="searchable">

        <li>
        <a id="btn-1" class="short-collapse-title" data-toggle="collapse" href="#btn-1-list" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="btn-1-list"><strong class="h5">Title</strong><br><span class="soft">Description</span><span class="hidden">keyword here</span></a>

            <div class="collapse indent-left" id="btn-1-list">
    <!--Other content-->                        
            </div> 

        </li>       

        <li>
        <a id="btn-2" class="short-collapse-title" data-toggle="collapse" href="#btn-2-list" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="btn-2-list"><strong class="h5">Title 2</strong><br><span class="soft">Description 2</span><span class="hidden">keyword here</span></a>

            <div class="collapse indent-left" id="btn-2list">                        
    <!--Other content-->                             
            </div>    
        </li>          

    </ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
// Click on categories (generic)   
$("#searchable>li>a").one("click", function() {                                 
    $("#content-right").empty();
    },
    function() {
    $("#searchable>li>a>.h5").clone().appendTo("#content-right-1");           
    $("#searchable>li>a>.soft").clone().appendTo("#content-right-2");         
});
```

Comment: Try selecting a specific element to clone, eg. the `first()`, or the `last()`, depending on how your logic needs to work.

Comment: Hello Rory, I tried that and it works, the only problem is that sometimes I have 10 <a> tags and so first and last are not enough.

Comment: Or you could change the click event to pass in the event object and get its target and clone the target element.

Comment: @Andrea in which case use `$(this).find('.h5').clone()...` and the same for `.soft`

Comment: Create first the elements #content-right-1 and #content-right-2...

Answer (score 0):

can you pls try this

```
$("#searchable>li>a").one("click", function() {                                 
    $("#content-right").empty();
    },
    function() {
    $(this).find(".h5").clone().appendTo("#content-right-1");           
    $(this).find(".soft").clone().appendTo("#content-right-2");         
});
```

Please let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you! This works but now I have another problem: when I click on another `<a>`, it doesn't "unclone" the others, the content just appears after the already cloned `<a>`'s. Is there something I'm missing here? I thought that the `empty()` function should have done just that.

Comment: can you please share your HTML code if possible. I wiil be happy to resolve all your problems.

Comment: I posted my code as an answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Andrea I am afraid, site moderators might down vote the answer(question), Is it possible for you to edit the question.

Comment: @Andrea other question is where is content-right element

Comment: I edited the question now. content-right is the parent div of content-right-1 and content-right-2, it is on the right of the page (on desktop) and invisible on mobile.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't empty the div and istead it keeps adding content each time I click lol

Comment: So, when you click on Title you want to wipe only content-2 items but not content-1 items, is that true. Sorry I am still understanding your requirements

Comment: Exactly. OR to simplify it: when you click on any <a> tag, I want the content-right to be emptied (or children divs but this is easy) and the new content to be cloned in.

Comment: then we should link <a> tag and content-2 items div by any of the data attribute ids. Is it possible for you to do that?

Comment: You mean the id's of each div? I could but I have like 150 <a>'s in my page.